# Exclude a local subnet from StrongSwan VPN

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, strongswan

I have a computer with an extra, local-only Ethernet interface, with a private subnet. When a StrongSwan VPN is established, I cannot access that subnet.

This is the local 'left' configuration (established by [algo](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo)):

```
conn ikev2-<rightip>
    fragmentation=yes
    rekey=no
    dpdaction=clear
    keyexchange=ikev2
    compress=no
    dpddelay=35s

    ike=aes128gcm16-prfsha512-ecp256!
    esp=aes128gcm16-ecp256!

    right=<rightip>
    rightid=<rightip>
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightauth=pubkey

    leftsourceip=%config
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=daves.crt
    leftfirewall=yes
    left=%defaultroute

    auto=add
```

The subnet in question is 10.0.0.0/24. %defaultroute resolves to an address in 192.168.0.0/24.

'left' and 'leftsubnet' don't look like the right options for this, but I see nothing better. I've tried setting leftsubnet to 10.0.0.0/24, and to !10.0.0.0/24.

How do I exclude a local subnet from a StronSwan VPN connection?

How do I inspect the route configuration of a connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a [passthrough policy](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/UsableExamples#Passthrough-policy).

UPDATE: as noted by @ecdsa, with strongswan >= 5.5.2 there's an [easier method](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Bypass-lan), look at the end if your version can use it.

Example with a few random IPs. Before any change and tunnel:

```
# ip route get 10.0.0.55
10.0.0.55 dev lxcbr0 src 10.0.0.77 uid 0
```

After establishing tunnel, the problem:

```
# ip route get 10.0.0.55
10.0.0.55 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table 220 src 192.168.0.44 uid 0
```

Adding this configuration to `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
conn ignorelan
    left=127.0.0.1 #prevents usage in peers selection algorithm
    leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
    authby=never
    type=passthrough
    auto=route
```

and reloading it:

```
# ipsec reload
```

should activate it immediately. If it didn't (this time) you can do:

```
# ipsec route ignorelan
'ignorelan' shunt PASS policy installed
```

Anyway it should be used on any later restart. You now have (in addition to any tunnel):

```
# ipsec status 
Shunted Connections:
     ignorelan:  10.0.0.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24 PASS
```

[...]

Now, tunnel being established or not, you get back the correct route (handled by strongswan, so in table 220, not (just) table main (anymore)):

```
# ip route get 10.0.0.55
10.0.0.55 dev lxcbr0 table 220 src 10.0.0.77 uid 0 
    cache
```

With a tunnel up for 0.0.0.0/0, there would be a result similar to this in table 220:

```
# ip route show table 220
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static src 192.168.0.44 
10.0.0.0/24 dev lxcbr0 proto static src 10.0.0.77 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto static src 192.168.0.44
```

If you don't put routes matching reality (eg: wrong netmask) in the passthrough settings, expect wrong results for the "shunt" (like the expected source IP, but going through the wrong network card), so be careful.

---

**UPDATE**: the [bypass-lan plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Bypass-lan) is easier to use, especially with dynamic environments.

Instead of adding new `conn` entries,  activate it (eg on Debian buster (not stable), edit /etc/strongswan.d/charon/bypass-lan.conf and set load=yes (ie: charon.plugins.bypass-lan.load=yes) ). By default every interface gets shunted, meaning a tunnel would establish, but wouldn't be used by default. So just set either `interfaces_ignore` or `interfaces_use` accordingly. You should set `interfaces_ignore` for the interface(s) you *don't want* to bypass tunnels or, else, set `interfaces_use` for the interface(s) you *want* to bypass tunnels. Eg:

```
interface_use = lxcbr0
```

Will get in this example after `ipsec start`, like the previous method:

```
# ip route show table 220
10.0.0.0/24 dev lxcbr0 proto static src 10.0.0.77
```

(but will also consider IPv6 routes related to this interface when IPv6 is in use).

---

Yet an other (hackish) method would be to bypass strongswan's table 220: 
instead of any strongswan settings, the same would be achieved (for these question and example) with:

```
ip rule add priority 219 to 10.0.0.0/24 lookup main
```

It will use the default (main) routing table with the target network instead of continuing to the next entry using strongswan's table 220.

Comment: Since 5.5.2, strongSwan also provides the [bypass-lan plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Bypass-lan) that automatically installs passthrough policies for locally attached subnets.

Comment: You have saved me, thank you!! Neither the `bypass-lan` plugin nor the `rightsubnet` split-tunnel approach did work for me with strongswan 5.8.2. But adding separate `conn ignorelan` passthrough entry did work.

Comment: bypass-lan plugin is real easy to use in docker, thanks a lot